# WPF Window in Window (c#)

Tags: c#, wpf, window, popupwindow, dynamic-content

I have a WPF Window in which I want to "open" other windows/interfaces. So that when I click on one of the labels, a "Popup" opens where I can do stuff (Input via a `Textbox`, images, buttons etc.). I already found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/popup-overview) but it seems that this is not really what i am looking for. Images below. Would be nice if someone could point me in the right direction.

**What I have**
[image: What I have]

**What I want to do/how it should look**
[image: What I want to do/how it should look]

Comment: Check custom in this link  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/dialog-boxes-overview

Answer (score 0):

This project shows how you can display dialog like content in a DropDownButton control:
https://github.com/Dirkster99/fsc/blob/master/source/Apps/FolderBrowserDemo/MainWindow.xaml

So, I think you probably do want a DropDownButton control like this:
https://github.com/Dirkster99/DropDownButtonLib

with a custom view as shown in your screenshot. This solution is quit advanced though but I hope it helps.